# Como guardar la response de una llamada HTTP como una variable

Tags: javascript, axios, response

Tengo una petición HTTP GET que estoy haciendo con Axios en JavaScript:

```
const BASE_URL_RECIBO = 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/appejemplo/Ejemplo&tabla?maxRecords=1000&view=Grid%20view';
async function polizas() {
    axios.get(`${BASE_URL_RECIBO}`, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.records)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
      });
};
```

No puedo guardar `response.data.records` como una variable porque Axios me está dando una promise por lo que entiendo.
Ni declarando una variable global y asignándole el valor dentro del `.then` . Lo he intentado casi todo.

Aunque no creo que importe, la respuesta es un array con varios JSON.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando `await` puedes acceder al valor de la respuesta y asignarlo a una variable:

```
async function polizas() {
   const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL_RECIBO}`, config);
   const records = response.data.records;

   return records;
};
```

Ten en cuenta que cuando ejecutes la funcion `polizas` igual tendras que utilizar `then` para acceder al valor a menos que la funcion que la ejecuta este marcada como `async` tambien:

```
elementoHtml.onClick = async (e)=>{
  const valor = await polizas()
  console.log(valor);
}
```

Si no esta marcada como `async` seria:

```
  elementoHtml.onClick = (e)=>{
      polizas().then(valor=>{
        console.log(valor);
      });
    }
```